# Tensorflow: how to find good neural network architectures/hyperparameters?

Tags: tensorflow, data-science

I've been using tensorflow on and off for various things that I guess are considered rather easy these days. Captcha cracking, basic OCR, things I remember from my AI education at university. They are problems that are reasonably large and therefore don't really lend themselves to experimenting efficiently with different NN architectures.

As you probably know, Joel Grus came out with FizzBuzz in tensorflow. TLDR: learning from a binary representation of a number (ie. 12 bits encoding the number) into 4 bits (none_of_the_others, divisible by 3, divisible by 5, divisible by 15). For this toy problem, you can quickly compare different networks.

So I've been trying a simple feedforward network and wrote a program to compare various architectures. Things like a 2-hidden-layer feedforward network, then 3 layers, different activation functions, ... Most architectures, well, suck. They get somewhere near 50-60 success rate and remain there, independent of how much training you do.

A few perform really well. For instance, a sigmoid-activated double hidden layer with 23 neurons each works really well (89-90% correct after 2000 training epochs). Unfortunately anything close to it is rather disastrously bad. Take one neuron out of the second or first layer and it drops to 30% correct. Same for taking it out of the first layer ... Single hidden layer, 20 neurons tanh activated does pretty well as well. But most have a little over half this performance.

Now given that for real problems I can't realistically do these sorts of studies of different architectures, are there ways to get good architectures guaranteed to work ?

Answer (score 3):

You might find the paper by Yoshua Bengio on [Practical Recommendations for Gradient-Based Training of Deep Architectures](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1206.5533.pdf) helpful to learn more about hyperparameters and their settings.

If you're asking specifically for settings that have more guaranteed succes, I advise you to read on Batch Normalization. I find that it decreases the failure rate for bad picks of the learning rate and weight initialization.

Some people also discourage the use of non-linearities like sigmoid() and tanh() as they suffer from the vanishing gradient problem